# IntelliJ SCSS/Sass File Watcher fails

Tags: intellij-idea, sass

I'm getting an error every time IntelliJ's SCSS File Watcher tries to transpile my `.scss` files into `.css` files. I know I've provided correct arguments, as I've use the exact same arguments on a different platform, and they've worked correctly there. Every time I make a change in a watched `.scss` file I get the following error in the Event Log:

```
An exception occurred while executing watcher 'SCSS'. Watcher has been disabled. Fix it.: Cannot run program "sass" (in directory "C:\Users\trevo\dev\projects\web\CaffeineSocket\styles\sass"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I've also tried giving it the path to Sass, and then the error changes to:

```
An exception occurred while executing watcher 'SCSS'. Watcher has been disabled. Fix it.: Cannot run program "C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\sass" (in directory "C:\Users\trevo\dev\projects\web\CaffeineSocket\styles\sass"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

How do I fix this and get my Sass/SCSS files to transpile?

Comment: Installing sass again fixed my issue  - sudo gem install sass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up needing to provide the path to the `.bat` file for Sass, and I did not realize (coming from Linux to Windows) that the `sass` file was not the executable, and that I rather needed to provide the `sass.bat` file.

For me, the full path to that file was `C:\Ruby24-x64\bin\sass.bat`.

To change this, you can either click on the `Fix it` linked text in IntelliJ's Event Log when you receive the error when the File Watcher fails, or you can get to the File Watcher by going through:

```
File --> Settings --> Tools --> File Watchers --> SCSS --> Edit (Enter) --> Watcher Settings --> Program:
```

Comment: You need to install sass globally - ```npm i sass -g```

Comment: @Leo I never mentioned using NodeJS...? Such a large library seems like overkill to add simply in order to use the Sass compiler, which I already have a solution to that does not require NodeJS.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. I agree with you and my case is just for NodeJS.